# Large data transfers break Azure cloud

Tags: azure, http, endpoint, large-data

I am getting this error when transferring large quantities of data;

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://XXXXXX.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

I cannot reproduce locally.

Also it does not happen when data sets are small.

This is the web.config of the service;

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <!--  To collect diagnostic traces, uncomment the section below or merge with existing system.diagnostics section.
        To persist the traces to storage, update the DiagnosticsConnectionString setting with your storage credentials.
        To avoid performance degradation, remember to disable tracing on production deployments.
  <system.diagnostics>     
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="AzureLocalStorage" type="WCFServiceWebRole1.AzureLocalStorageTraceListener, WCFServiceWebRole1"/>
    </sharedListeners>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="AzureLocalStorage"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="AzureLocalStorage"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources> 
   </system.diagnostics> -->
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength ="2147483647" executionTimeout="999999"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <!-- Large Message Upload (Begin) -->
        <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:50:00" openTimeout="00:50:00" sendTimeout="00:50:00" receiveTimeout="00:50:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <!-- Large Message Upload (End) -->
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

In the IIS event logs I see this; A process serving application pool '30e0a5e5-b137-43df-ae0a-2db5b7c33dc0' failed to respond to a ping. The process id was '1180'.

In the httperr log I see this;
2014-09-17 19:00:03 94.195.39.139 56651 100.74.230.46 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /Service1.svc - 1273337584 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue 30e0a5e5-b137-43df-ae0a-2db5b7c33dc0

Comment: If you haven't already, I suggest updating to the most current versions of your client libraries (AzureSDK and Storage)

Comment: The problem seems to be related to IIS. This is such a pain, I am not even interested in setting up a "website", I just want to use web services as a way of distributing my computations.

Comment: How long does the transfer last before failing? Is it consistently the same amount of time or does it vary?

Comment: 2 minutes. it's the same everytime.

Comment: It does not happen when running the WCF service in visual studio. I  installed VS on the azure VM and ran the WCF on the VM in that, no problems. It is only when it is deployed as a cloud service that it exhibits this behaviour.